# python dataframe new column based on another column with value of conditional min of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called 'result' as follows:

|  | ddate | sstart | ttime | H | L | C | key | usteps | dsteps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20110427.0 | 140500.0 | 141000.0 | 0.00012 | -0.00112 | -0.00112 | 1 | 0.001 | -0.00100 |
| 1 | 20110427.0 | 140500.0 | 141000.0 | 0.00012 | -0.00112 | -0.00112 | 1 | 0.001 | -0.00125 |
| 2 | 20110427.0 | 140500.0 | 141000.0 | 0.00012 | -0.00112 | -0.00112 | 1 | 0.001 | -0.00150 |
| 3 | 20110427.0 | 140500.0 | 141000.0 | 0.00012 | -0.00112 | -0.00112 | 1 | 0.001 | -0.00175 |
| 4 | 20110427.0 | 140500.0 | 141000.0 | 0.00012 | -0.00112 | -0.00112 | 1 | 0.001 | -0.00200 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to add another column call "dtime" with the value:

> result.groupby("ddate").get_group(%%ddate%%).loc[(result.L < %%dsteps%% )  , "ttime"].min()

I tried `result.groupby("ddate").get_group(20110427).loc[(result.L < -0.0015)  , "ttime"].min()` for single row and it works well.

I run the foillowig command:

```
result['dtime'] =result.groupby("ddate").get_group(result['ddate']).loc[(result.L < result['dsteps'])  , "ttime"].min()
```

it returns 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

1. Why is it wrong ?
2. What should the command be?

Comment: Please provide an example of your desired output.

Comment: `result.ddate` and `result['ddate']` are the same column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.. it should be
`result['dtime'] =result.apply(lambda row: result.groupby("ddate").get_group(row['ddate']).loc[(result.L < row['dsteps'])  , "ttime"].min() , axis=1)`